# .net 4 sql bulk insert on 64bit iis 7

Tags: .net, iis, unicode, 64-bit, sqlbulkcopy

i need to import some bulk data in an asp.net application from txt/csv files

until now i used SqlBulkCopy, but now on iis7 with 64bit it doesn't work. there are many posts about jet not working with 64bit.

i read that iis can be configured to work in 32 bit mode, but id rather keep performance as good as possible via 64bit.

additionally, i never quite managed to make sqlbulkcopy use the extended properties (as you might see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305502/net-sqlbulkcopy-with-unicode-chars or here http://forums.asp.net/p/1627034/4184689.aspx#4184689?SqlBulkCopy+DATAFILETYPE+widechar)

so the question is, is there another/better method to import bulk records to mssql via .net? something that works fine with 64bit and allows for customization as to unicode & filetypes?

thank you all for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers, fellows.

though it seems that the easiest way to go, is manually. so i started writing some code myself. and ill post it here if anyone might find some interest in it

it may not cover everything, but it is pretty flexible.

it does use some of my helper functions and such, not listed here, so if you're reading this and cannot figure out something, ill be glad to elaborate :-)

```
Sub ImportFile(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal RecordType As ObjectType, Optional ByVal HasHeaders As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal RowDelimiter As String = ControlChars.Tab, Optional ByVal CellDelimiter As String = ControlChars.NewLine)
    Dim objReader = New StreamReader(FilePath)
    Dim strContents = objReader.ReadToEnd
    objReader.Close()
    Dim Columns = New List(Of String)
    Dim axName = ObjectType.Account.GetType.Assembly.FullName
    Dim objRecord = Activator.CreateInstance(axName, RecordType.ToString).Unwrap
    Dim dcx = DBContext()
    dcx.EditLogging = False
    Dim tbl = dcx.GetTable(objRecord.GetType)

    Dim TableColumns = New List(Of String)
    For Each p In objRecord.GetType.GetProperties
        If (p.PropertyType.BaseType IsNot Nothing AndAlso p.PropertyType.BaseType.Name = "ValueType") Or p.PropertyType Is "".GetType Then TableColumns.Add(p.Name)
    Next

    Dim Rows = Split(strContents, RowDelimiter).ToList
    If HasHeaders Then
        Columns = Rows(0).Split(CellDelimiter).ToList
        Rows.RemoveAt(0)
        'check validity
        For Each clm In Columns
            If Not TableColumns.Contains(clm) Then Throw New ApplicationException(clm & " is not a valid column name.")
        Next
    Else
        Columns = TableColumns
    End If
    For Each row In Rows
        objRecord = Activator.CreateInstance(axName, RecordType.ToString).Unwrap
        Dim Cells = row.Split(CellDelimiter)
        For i = 0 To Cells.Count - 1
            SetObjProperty(objRecord, Columns(i), Cells(i))
        Next
        tbl.InsertOnSubmit(objRecord)
    Next
    dcx.SubmitChanges()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Sql Server Integration Services
You can easily create an "Import Data" package in SQL Management studio and call that from you .net code.

Comment: hi thank you very much. meanwhile i get this message. In SQL Server Express, Web, or Workgroup, you can run the package that the Import and Export Wizard creates, but cannot save it. To save packages that the wizard creates, you must upgrade to SQL Server Standard, Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation.  BUT I AM NOT USING EXPRESS. this is the full version i downloaded from websitespark. im not sure of the exact edition. anywhere to check this? but i do have sql profiler and other advanced tools that are not in the express. thanks

Comment: ok, i now see i have something called "web edition". which does not allow saving these imports. any other idea?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at FileHelpers; they provide csv import functionality.  It's a good library

Comment: Hmm. never heard of this. thank you. ive downloaded it. it seems like a lot of functionality, but a very complex and old/patchey solution. FWIW, i think ill try now to write my own parser for the 1 doc i need at the moment. but will keep this in mind, if i needed much more functionality. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get x64 Jet, but not sure if SqlBulkCopy supports it,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/01/21/how-to-get-a-x64-version-of-jet.aspx

Comment: i see. thank you. do they offer an alternative anywhere? i think ill take off jet from my list as its ancient and deprecated. the question is, what would be the right way for imports in the current era?